# Is there a kink solution in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, field-theory, classical-field-theory, non-linear-systems

In the special case of the $\phi^4$ scalar field theory in special relativity, a nice "kink" solution is very well known:
$$\tag{1}
\phi(z) = v \tanh \Bigl(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2}} \: v \, z \Bigr),
$$
which is a static solution to the non-linear wave equation
$$\tag{2}
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z^2} + \lambda (\phi^2 - v^2) \, \phi = 0.
$$
The scalar field potential is the "mexican hat":
$$\tag{3}
\mathcal{V}(\phi) = \frac{\lambda}{4}(\phi^2 - v^2)^2.
$$
The kink (1) asymptotically connects the two "true-vaccum" solutions:
$$\tag{4}
\lim_{z \rightarrow \pm \, \infty} \phi(z) = \pm \, v.
$$
Now, I wonder if a similar **simple analytical** solution exists in general relativity.  Is there:

1. A simple kink style metric solution, associated to any kind of matter-energy?
2. A simple (or not?) metric solution associated to the kink (1), probably modified by its own gravity?

---

**EDIT:** As a first try, I postulated a metric of the following shape, considering a static "kink" with symmetry around the $z$ axis:
$$\tag{5}
ds^2 = \mathcal{P}^2(z) dt^2 - \mathcal{Q}^2(z) (dx^2 + dy^2) - dz^2.
$$
Plugging this into the Einstein equation (without cosmological constant) gave the following equations:
\begin{align}
G_{00} &= - 2 \frac{\mathcal{Q}^{\prime \prime}}{\mathcal{Q}} + \frac{\mathcal{Q}^{\prime 2}}{\mathcal{Q}^2} = -\, \kappa T_{00} \equiv - \kappa \rho, \tag{6} \\[2ex]
G_{11} &= \frac{\mathcal{P}^{\prime \prime}}{\mathcal{P}} + \frac{\mathcal{Q}^{\prime \prime}}{\mathcal{Q}} - \frac{\mathcal{P}^{\prime} \mathcal{Q}^{\prime}}{\mathcal{P} \mathcal{Q}} = - \kappa T_{11}, \tag{7} \\[2ex]
G_{33} &= - 2 \frac{\mathcal{P}^{\prime} \mathcal{Q}^{\prime}}{\mathcal{P} \mathcal{Q}} - \frac{\mathcal{Q}^{\prime 2}}{\mathcal{Q}^2} = - \kappa T_{33}. \tag{8}
\end{align}
By symmetry: $G_{22} = G_{11}$.  For a "wall", I assume that $T_{11} = T_{22} = -\, \rho$ and $T_{33} = 0$.

---

**EDIT2:**  I've found a solution to equations (6)-(8), assuming the constraints above on the energy-momentum tensor:
\begin{align}\tag{9}
\mathcal{P}(z) &= \alpha z,
&\mathcal{Q}(z) &= \frac{1}{\alpha^2 z^2},
&\kappa \rho(z) &= \frac{8}{z^2} > 0,
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ is a constant.  The metric (5) then is
$$\tag{10}
ds^2 = \alpha^2 z^2 dt^2 - \frac{1}{\alpha^4 z^4}(dx^2 + dy^2) - dz^2.
$$
I never saw this metric before, which has a planar singularity at $z = 0$.  I don't know if it's making any sense.